# C# regular expression for sentence that may be encompassed with any non-alphabetic chrachter

Tags: c#, regex, full-text-search

I need general instruction to search for sentence or single word inside text that is preceded and followed by any non-alphabetic character..
i will give a few examples to illustrate what i need:

search for "good luck" :

```
good luck in the exam.. (should match the pattern)
hello! good luck in the exam..  (should match)
mm,good luck! ..  (should match)
hello again i wish yougood luckin the exam. (**should Not match**)
```

i mean the regular expression should match the sentence when it is not encompassed with alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String regex=@"\b"+input+@"\b";
```

`\b` is a non word boundary..Simply put,it would let you match individual words i.e a word which is not a part of another word

---

**NOTE** You should escape input,because if your input contains characters like `*`,`?`.. it would be treated as a special characters in regex..So,it should be

```
String regex=@"\b"+Regex.Escape(input)+@"\b";
```